# Using Observable.ajax.post is it possible to catch the 'correct/custom' error?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, redux-observable

When I use `Observable.ajax.post` and get an error, it returns a "generic" `AjaxError`.

In my Web Service I return a custom json object that contains the error along with a BadRequest (400) response. If I test the service in *SwaggerUI* I have the "correct" error message/object.

**Is it a limitation of `Observable.ajax` to return only a "generic" `AjaxError`?**

*A bit more about the context, I'm developping a SPA using React, Redux, Redux-Observable (with RxJs), TypeScript, Webpack and the service is a Asp.Net Core WebApi using Swagger (Swashbuckle).*

Thanks,
Adrien.

Answer (score 0):

In AjaxError there is a xhr object of type XMLHttpRequest, you can use the response field of xhr object (e.g. error.xhr.response) to handle error response.

Comment: The custom error json/object returned by the service is not in the xhr.response. I didn't find my error message in the whole response.

Comment: I would suggest that you check the response tab in chrome developer console for the request, it may provide more inside into the problem.

Comment: The only message I got is `{"":["The input was not valid."]}`. That is clearly not my custom error message and not even close to the error returned by the SwaggerUI.

Comment: This is what my error looks like : `{
  "PhoneNumber": [
    "The PhoneNumber field is not a valid phone number."
  ]
}`

Comment: This definitely works, https://jsbin.com/goheka/edit?js,output "The input was not valid" does not come from RxJS, so it must come from your code or the server's response.

Comment: @Adrien did you figure out where "The input was not valid" is coming from? and solve your issue?

Comment: It seems to work but we haven't changed *any line* of code ... I only remove the Swagger UI on the server. I can't picture why this change could possibly have an impact. I can't check or do more test for now, the website went live yesterday.